# Isometry between $C^\infty_c$ and radially symmetric functions in the unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $B$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$ e consider
$$
\mathcal{R}(B) = \{u \in C^{\infty}_c(B) : u \text{ is radially symmetric}\}.
$$
I woul like to know if $\mathcal{R}(B)$ is isometric to $C^{\infty}_c(B)$ under the $H^1_0(B)$ norm, that is, $||u||_{H^1_0(B)} = ||\nabla u||_{L^2(B)}$.

**The context:** In a paper, the author take $E$ as the completion of $\mathcal{R}(B)$ under the $||\cdot||_{H^1_0(B)}$, that is, $E$ is a Banach space which has a dense subspace isometrically to $\mathcal{R}(B)$. My question is justified because $C^\infty_c(B)$ is dense in $H^1_0(B)$.  Actually I'm not sure if my question makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find whether there exists an isometry between $\mathcal{R}(B)$ and $C^\infty_c(B)$. The first space $\mathcal{R}(B)$ is given the $H^1_0(B)$ norm, but what about the second space?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vizietto.  I think the norm in $C^\infty_c(B)$ is also the $H^1_0(B)$ norm. However, I'm not completely sure. If you have a suggestion of another norm which works would be nice.

Comment: Unclear why you'd want/need an isometry anyway. $H^1_0(B)$ has a Banach subspace which is the one of radially symmetric functions.

Comment: But is the space $\mathcal{R}(B)$ dense in $H^1_0(B)$?

Comment: Well if your concern is to know whether $E$ and $H^1_0(B)$ are isometric, then... they are, because they are both separable Hilbert space. But this isometry does not tell us much.

Comment: no $\mathcal{R}(B)$ is certainly not dense in $H^1_0(B)$.

Comment: I didn't know that $E$ was also separable. I think the author of the paper meant what you have said. Thanks.